# Find remote desktop gateway server

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, remote-connection, remote-login

I saw in a tutorial that if we use the full computer name and the remote desktop gateway server of the work PC, we can easily get connected with it.

I got my work PC's name, but could not find the remote desktop gateway server address.

Comment: What tutorial are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask whomever administers your network what the fully qualified host name of your Remote Desktop Gateway server is.  There's no way for you to determine this information based simply off the name of your work PC.